# Arreglos en PHP con Netbeans IDE

Tags: php, array

Necesito realizar en PHP un registro donde cada persona esté dentro del listado.

Debo evaluar si el nombre del color existente en un segundo arreglo que contiene el nombre del color y el significado de cada uno, en caso de encontrarlo, es necesario escribir en una última columna de la Tabla mostrada, el significado del color, de lo contrario debe escribir la frase “No se encuentra el significado”.

[image: Tabla deseada]

Hasta el momento sólo he podido hacer los listados, pero no me muestra el significado del color, agradecería me ayudarán.

[image: Tavla obtenida sin significado]

Este es mi código hasta el momento.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Arreglos Listado Agenda Telefonica</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
              content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Listado Agenda</h3>
        <?php
        /* En este programa se va a especificar la forma de
         * declarar arreglos y acceder a la información que contiene
         */
        //Arreglo con llaves numéricas
        $cabecera=array("Nombre","Direccion","Telefono", "Fecha de Cumpleanos", "Color Favorito", "Significado");
        $nombres=array("Jimmy Riera","Valera","041412345678", "05/01/1976", "Amarillo");
        $direccion=array("Antonio Lopez","Motatan","041245612378", "08/02/1976", "Rojo");
        $telefono=array("Paola Reverol","Pampan","04145551212", "15/12/2000", "Verde");
        $fechaCumple=array("Manuela Saez","Trujillo","0272-5552212", "31/06/1999", "Rosado");
        $color=array("Juan Rojo","Valera","041412345678", "05/01/1976", "Azul");
        $directorio=array($cabecera,$nombres,$direccion,$telefono,$fechaCumple,$color);
        $key=array("Amarillo", "Riqueza-Pureza");
        $result = isset($colores[$key]) ? $array[$key] : "No se encuentra el significado";
        ?>
<table border="1" width="60%" cellspacing="0">
<?php
foreach ($directorio as $fila){
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($fila as $celda){
                echo "<td> $celda </td>";
                }
        echo "</tr>";
        }
?>
</table>
     </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para responder a tu pregunta hice ligeros cambios en tu código, cambié el arreglo `$cabecera` por `$cabeceras` y lo quite del arreglo `$directorio` para poder iterar sobre ambos arreglos

El código quedó de esta manera

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Arreglos Listado Agenda Telefonica</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
  content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
  <h3>Listado Agenda</h3>
  <?php
  /* En este programa se va a especificar la forma de
   * declarar arreglos y acceder a la información que contiene
   */
  //Arreglo con llaves numéricas
  // Arreglo de cabeceras
  $cabeceras=array("Nombre","Direccion","Telefono", "Fecha de Cumpleanos", "Color Favorito", "Significado");
  // Directorio
  $nombres=array("Jimmy Riera","Valera","041412345678", "05/01/1976", "Amarillo");
  $direccion=array("Antonio Lopez","Motatan","041245612378", "08/02/1976", "Rojo");
  $telefono=array("Paola Reverol","Pampan","04145551212", "15/12/2000", "Verde");
  $fechaCumple=array("Manuela Saez","Trujillo","0272-5552212", "31/06/1999", "Rosado");
  $color=array("Juan Rojo","Valera","041412345678", "05/01/1976", "Azul");
  $directorio=array($nombres,$direccion,$telefono,$fechaCumple,$color);
  $key=array("Amarillo" => "Riqueza-Pureza");
  ?>
  <table border="1" width="60%" cellspacing="0">
    <?php
    // Iteramos sobre las cabeceras
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($cabeceras as $cabecera) {
      echo "<td> $cabecera </td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    // Iteramos sobre el directorio
    foreach ($directorio as $fila) {
      echo "<tr>";
      foreach ($fila as $llave => $celda) {
        echo "<td> $celda </td>";
        // Revisamos que nos encontramos en el índice que contiene el color e imprimimos
        // el sifnificado
        if ($llave === 4) {
          echo "<td>";
          echo isset($key[$celda]) ? $key[$celda] : "No se encuentra el significado";
          echo "</td>";
        }
      }
      echo "</tr>";
    }
  ?>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Imprime esto:
[image: Output del código]

**Recomendación:**

Esto no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta es una simple recomendación que alguna vez me la hicieron y me ha ayudado al programar.

Te sugiero que por legibilidad mantengas tus nombres de variables consistentes con lo que contienen, por ejemplo el arreglo `$nombres` podrías llamarlo `$jimmy` o `$persona1` y así sucesivamente

Comment: Gracias @kacos Me ayudaste 100%..